# Is Windows Communication Foundation the better alternative to the use of web and windows services

Tags: web-services, wcf, windows-services

I was reading through introductory articles about windows communication foundation on MSDN and it looked to me like an alternative to using a windows or web services -  (a much better alternative i thought). Is this the case or did i miss some thing - And yes i didn't read deeply.

It looked to me like WCF is a better option to a windows or web service. Am looking to listen to people who have a better understanding of both technologies about this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Comparing WCF to webservices might make sense, but WCF vs Windows services really doesn't. They're different technologies used for different purposes, sometimes it might make sense to make a WCF service be a Windows Service.

Quotes from wikipedia:

> a Windows service is a long-running executable that performs specific functions and which is designed not to require user intervention
>
> The Windows Communication Foundation (or WCF) is an application programming interface in the .NET Framework for building connected, service-oriented applications.

So as you see, they're quite different.